# How do I parse an ISO-8601 formatted string that contains no punctuation in Java 8?

Tags: java, localdate

How could I parse the following String to a `LocalDateTime`-Object?

20200203092315000000

I always get the following exception but I didn't understand it:

```java
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20200203092315000000' could not be parsed at index 0

    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at de.x.struct.type.LocalDateTimeStructField.setBytesValue(LocalDateTimeStructField.java:44)
    at de.x.struct.Struct.bytesToStruct(Struct.java:110)
    at de.x.struct.StructTest.testStringToStruct(StructTest.java:60)
```

My application code looks like:

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("20200203092315000000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSSSS"));
```

Comment: `20200203092315000000` is not a valid date.

Comment: @Modo: It looks reasonable to me, given the pattern. I'd expect it to be equivalent to 2020-02-03T09:23:15.000000 in ISO format.

Comment: That exact code works for me. Could you provide a [mcve] that fails, and include any cultural information? (And Java version information too?)

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right. I thought those were milliseconds and did not bother looking at the pattern provided.

Comment: Your code work fine with me, check this https://www.ideone.com/WjA9E2

Comment: which java version? works fine using java 11

Comment: FYI I have the same issue (java 8)
What's also strange this pattern seems to work just fine: MMddHHmmssSSSSSSyyyy & yyyy-MMddHHmmssSSSSSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like a known issue...

[bug_id=JDK-8031085](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8031085)
[bug_id=JDK-8138676](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8138676)

> Workaround:
>
> DateTimeFormatter dtf = new
>   DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND,
>   3).toFormatter()

or

> CUSTOMER SUBMITTED WORKAROUND : use the following format (mind the
>   '.'): "yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS"
>
> LocalDateTime.parse("20150910121314987",
>   DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS"))
>
> or alternatively use jodatime library

Comment: this also works for "yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSSSS" and you can place the . almost anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the following code for close to three years and it has served me well.

ISO 8601 allows two formats: basic and extended. The basic format does not contain any punctuation while the extended format does. For example, 2017-12-10T09:47:00-04:00 in extended format is equivalent to 20171210T094700-0400 in basic format.

Since the behavior in Java 8 is to only accept the extended format, I typically use a new DateTimeFormatter that accepts both.

This format is not an accurate representation of what ISO 8601 requires. The rule is that a textual representation of a timestamp either be completely basic (i.e., no punctuation) or completely extended (i.e., all punctuation present). It is not valid to have just some punctuation but I have found that some libraries do not honor this rule. Specifically, Gson produces timestamps with the colon missing in the time zone specifier. Since I wish to be liberal in what I accept, I completely ignore all punctuation.

Java 8 also fails to accurately handle years especially when the punctuation is missing. ISO 8601 requires exactly four digits in the year but allows extra digits if both parties agree on an explicit number of digits. In this case, the year MUST be preceded by a sign. However, Java 8 does not enforce the requirement to have a sign and accepts from four to nine digits. While this approach is more liberal and in keeping with what I am usually trying to accomplish, it makes it impossible to parse a year since I cannot know how many digits should be present. I tighten the format to honor ISO 8601 in this case although an alternative approach is available if needed. For example, you could pre-parse the text knowing how many digits you expect and add the sign if there are too many digits.

I recommend only using this formatter when parsing and not when serializing since I prefer to be strict in what I produce.

The code below should accept your format, with and without a timezone offset. It only deviates in what you have in that it accepts nine digits for the fractional seconds instead of six. You can adjust it if needed.

```java
// somewhere above
import java.time.format.SignStyle;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.*;

static DateTimeFormatter ISO_8601_LENIENT_FORMAT = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 4, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
    .optionalStart().appendLiteral('-').optionalEnd()   // Basic format has no punctuation
    .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
    .optionalStart().appendLiteral('-').optionalEnd()
    .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
    .optionalStart().appendLiteral('T').optionalEnd()   // permitted to omit the 'T' character by mutual agreement
    .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
    .optionalStart().appendLiteral(':').optionalEnd()
    .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .optionalStart()                                    // seconds are optional
    .optionalStart().appendLiteral(':').optionalEnd()
        .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
        .optionalStart().appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, false).optionalEnd()
    .optionalEnd()
    .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HH:MM", "Z").optionalEnd()
    .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HHMM", "Z").optionalEnd()
    .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HH", "Z").optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter()
    ;
```

A more strict version that rejects all punctuation, assumes non-negative years, limits fractional seconds to six digits and omits timezone information follows.

```java
static DateTimeFormatter ISO_8601_NO_PUNCTUATION = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 4, SignStyle.NEVER)
    .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
    .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
    .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
    .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 6, 6, false)
    .toFormatter()
    ;
```

Answer (score -3):

your input is not valid and its out of range.

use this code when your input is correct.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(your input * 1000);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: Well... using the _old_ `java.util` date api like `Calendar` isn't what the OP is requesting: "How could I parse the following String to a LocalDateTime-Object?" (that's using the _new_ `java.time` api)

Comment: the input is valid

Comment: Also note that 20200203092315000000 does _not_ represent the number of milliseconds since the epoch but rather an actual timestamp in 2020. Thus your method would result in the wrong value anyway.